# How to download uri data:text file using R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, uri

I'm trying to download what I believe is called a URI data:text file using R. The "URL" is of this form:

URL <- "data:text/csv;charset=utf8,Supply%2001%2F02%2F2020%2C0%3A00%2C0%3A05%2C0%3A10%2C0%3A15%2C0..."

followed by hundreds more characters. When I type the "URL" into a web browser and press enter, the desired CSV file downloads without a problem. When I try to use something like download.file or curl_download on the above string, however, I get an error like this:

Error in curl_download(URL, destfile = "test1234.csv") :
Port number ended with 't'

Any insights on how I can download a csv data: file like this using R?  Thanks!

If it's any use, the file I'm trying to download is pasted below. I had to first save the string as a .txt file and then import that .txt file with read_file in order to store it as a string in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data URL isn't really a normal URL, it contains all the data inside of the text rather than pointing to the data at a different location. It is made up of two parts: a "header" and then data itself. The header consist of "data:text/csv;charset=utf8," and then the data follows, but it's been HTML (or URL) encoded. You can read the data by removing the header, decoding the values, and then reading the text as a CSV file with `read.csv`. For example:'

```
read.csv(text=URLdecode(gsub("^data:text/csv;charset=utf8,","", URL)), 
   check.names = FALSE)
```